# Importing Gauge.js into react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to import a javascript gauge script (http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js) into my component to use.

I copy the script from (http://bernii.github.io/gauge.js/dist/gauge.min.js) into my components folder renamed to (Gauge.js) and require it.

```
var Gauge = require('./Gauge');
```

I then try to create the gauge script using it's constructor like so, this is used in componentDidMount().

`var target = this.refs.test;
        var gauge = new Gauge(target);`

My render

`render() {
        return(
            <div className="GaugeTest">
                <canvas width={this.props.width} height={this.props.height} ref="test" />
            </div>
        );
    }`

I get the error:

**Overview.js:34 Uncaught TypeError: Gauge is not a constructor** This is referring to the line that has this code on it:

```
var gauge = new Gauge(target);
```

Any idea on how to include/require this script so I can use it in my component?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: For gauge specifically, I used react-gaugejs , you can also just include it normally in HTML file using a cdn or local file. Other option is to use webpack and aliases to import these scripts in. More info on the web about that.

Comment: Ended up figuring it out. I consoled Gauge and found it was returning as an object itself with Gauge (and others) as a key. So I just did `var gauge = new Gauge.Gauge(target);` and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

It’s being imported as an object with Gauge (and other options) as a key. So instead do:

```
var Gauge = Gauge.Gauge(target);
```

If you want to see why just `console.log(Gauge)`

Comment: I was trying to convert the library to classes and failed.
Your response saved my day :)